# "My friend gave it to me" vs. "I got it 'off'/'from' my friend"

Tags: prepositions

Could one replace, whitout changing in meaning, "my friend gave it to me" with "I got it **off** my friend"?

Searching on Internet I came across several instances of "I got it off my chest", but, alas, I found practically no notable hits for "got it off [my](*a person*)".

Does this mean that "I got it **off** my chest" is idiomatic English, so we cannot extend "got it off" to person cases? What does it happen if one uses "from" rather than "off" in "I got it **off** my friend"?

Answer (score 6):

To **get something off your chest** is an idiom. It basically means "talk about something that is upsetting you".

As for **I got it off my friend** --- in the UK at least people will understand this (and use it themselves), but it is informal and is not really proper English. In an informal spoken setting you could happily use it, but I wouldn't use it when writing.

Comment: I think the phrase is more common with taking an idea or design from another source and integrating it into your own, such as "I got the image off a website", or "he got the idea off a movie".

Comment: One might also say "I got it off (Amazon|eBay|the internet)". Interestingly enough, I've often heard "off the internet" and "online" combined to an unexpected "I got it offline".

Comment: @Jim and now "I got it offline" has turned into a strange idiomatic phrase in business meetings when someone says "do you want to take this offline" to mean, "do you want to talk about this more in-depth after the meeting, with fewer people?"

Comment: @TrishRempel is correct --- its definitely a phrase you'd associate with *taking* something, but it has made its way into common (spoken) usage (at least it has in the UK).

Comment: I can attest to US usage at least in the Northeast. As Kristina Lopez mentions, it *might* imply theft, but not very strongly in my experience. I can also attest to it being used in the context of physical objects (candy, toys, guns, money)

Answer (score 5):

***"Got it off my friend"***, from my region (or maybe era), can mean that you stole it from your friend.  "I got it from my friend" or "My friend gave it to me" are the clearer choices.

For what it's worth, the difference between the two is that "My friend gave it to me" implies it is now yours.  "I got it from my friend" could mean that they loaned it to you.

Comment: @Carlo_R., How could I refuse such a gracious invitation? :-)

Comment: You can use it in other contexts - in *"I got it off eBay"* for example, you probably *paid* for it (it wasn't a gift or a loan, and you didn't steal it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, true, and some of the comments mentioned examples of this as well, "off of the internet", etc. It's good to add other examples of "getting it off" for comparison.  My answer is narrowly defined as getting it "off" a person, based on the OP's example.

Comment: @Kristina: Yes, but even if you *got it off John*, you still might have *paid* John for it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, true again, but *my* knowledge of "got it off John" usually implies I stole it from him.  I would not use "got it off John" if I paid for it - again, from my perspective (middle-aged midwestern US). :-)

Comment: @Kristina: It's interesting that both our comments here are getting upvotes. Perhaps this is a UK/US distinction - it wouldn't occur to me that you might have *stolen* whatever it was you got off John (perhaps that's the advantage of having an honest-looking face on your profile! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I would have to dig a little to see if my interpretation is still being used - it could have been a fad from my youth!

Comment: In my youth (50s-60s) and region (East Alabama) *get it offa* (or *offen*, both = 'off of') had no larcenous implication. It embraced gift, purchase, loan or theft.

Comment: @Kristina: Tsk. When you were a young tearaway inclined to nick stuff, perhaps! :)

Comment: "nick", "cop", "snitch", "5-finger discount" all while wearing a Girl Scout uniform  . . . so goes the (false, of course) rumors!

Comment: @StoneyB theft is not larceny?

Comment: @mcalex It does not *imply* theft, though it may be used in that context.

Answer (score 1):

No, not without changing the meaning. When you say "I got it off my friend," we know that the item came from your friend, but it is ambiguous whether or not you took it with your friend's permission.